# How to detect tap gesture on a page slider having 3 images on the slider in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider

I have three images on the slider and when I click on those slider images it should be directed to a view controller but when we tap on image 1 it should open a different web view than that of image 2 and image 3.
These are the coding for the view controller I want to display the web view so basically, I want to know how to detect that image one is clicked ,have a button in the image view .

when the button was pressed it should detect its image 1,2 or 3 so I don't know what condition to put so that it detect that first image on the slider is clicked.
My image name is slider1,slider2 n slider 3

- (void) buttonTapped:(id)sender
  {
  NSLog(@"it works");

  {
      [self.delegate1 buttonWasPressed];
  }

}

```
-(void) buttonWasPressed
{
NSLog(@"hello");

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

LeaguesViewController* Leagues = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Leagues"];
    }
       if (Leagues.imageFile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider1"]);
        [self presentViewController:Leagues animated:YES completion:nil];
    if ([imageFile isEqual:@"slider1"]){

```
    NSURL *slider1url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://code4app.net/category/menu"];

    [self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:slider1url]];
```

Comment: why you are editing the que ?

Comment: Please, please, please format your code properly, so it becomes understandable. I tried to do it for you, but the result makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should create button method with sender, than you can add different tags for your image buttons and check that tag inside your method.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
   if ([sender tag] == 1) {
       NSLog(@"First image tapped");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"Second or third image tapped");
   }
 }
```

Comment: How to call this method bcaz when i call this method it is giving me an error

Comment: How to call this method as its giving me error when i add (UIbutton * )sender in it  if (self.delegate1 && [self.delegate1 respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonWasPressed)])
        
    {
        [self.delegate1 buttonWasPressed];
    }           // [delegate1 buttonWasPressed];

Comment: when you're creating outlet from Interface Builder it asks you if you need to set "Arguments" field to "sender", when you was creating your code you probably picked "none" that's why you don't have "sender" parameter there. And if you call it directly, than it requires UIButton for argument, so you can't call it without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can assign a tags for a buttons like button above image-1 should be 1 and 2, 3

As per your request I have created a screenshot which will explain how to set a tag to a button using XIB or storyboard you can find the screenshot attached below,
[image: How to set a tag to UIButton]

Then you can write a method with sender like below,

```
-(void) buttonWasPressed:(UIButton)sender { 
    switch (sender.tag) {
       case 1 :
       // open your webview
       case 2: 
       // write your code here if other than opening view controller
       default : 
      // open view controllers
     }
}
```

Comment: Can u plz elaborate it as I didn't understood how exactly to do this

Comment: give me a min, I will add some screenshot along with description in the answer.

Comment: I have added button on slider imageview like this programattically UIButton * ButtonOnImageView = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        
        
        [ButtonOnImageView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//        ButtonOnImageView.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
        
        
        
        [imageView addSubview:ButtonOnImageView];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];

Comment: Then you can simply assign the tags to the buttons like
ButtonOnImageView.tag = 1

Comment: @user6584316 does it helps you ?

Comment: No actually i m using only one button for all three images n that too not by storyboard but programmatically so this doesnt work with it but thanks anyways.

Comment: you should have used either 3 different buttons for it or add tap gesture recognizer to your image view and use the method for it